# Restricting an Element of the Selmer Group to the Decompositiongroup for some place v

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, group-cohomology

My question is the following:
Let $\phi: E \rightarrow E \prime$ be a non-zero isogeny between elliptic curves, defined over some numberfield K. Then we can define the Selmer-group $Sel^{\phi}(E/K)$. Moreover let $v \in M_K$ be a place of K and $G_v \subset Gal(\bar{K}/K)$ its decompositiongroup. Take some $\xi \in Sel^{\phi}(E/K)$ and consider the restriction map $res_v: Sel^{\phi}(E/K) \rightarrow H¹(G_v, E[\phi])$. Is it true that $res_v(\xi)=0$ for almost every place $v \in M_K$?
I would appreciate every helpful comment! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the definition that the restriction map is zero for *all* $v$?

Comment: No, by definition it will be trivial in $H¹(G_v,E)[\phi]$, which is much easier since E is much "bigger" than $E[\phi]$